# Can Turbo.visit update a turbo frame when onChange changes, without changing the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

Inside a form we have 2 `select` and would like to refresh/update the second `select` when the **first** `select` changes, using `onChange`

**Example:**

First `select` has:

```js
onChange:"Turbo.visit(`/sites/index_by_country?country_id=${this.value}`)"
```

Currently this works, but `Turbo.visit` updates the URL also - which we don't want.
We only want the frame to update (which it does) and not update the URL.

Or should we be using a different approach?

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281610/load-a-turbo-frame-with-a-select-onchange-event